# Clarification on behavior of BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeroes()

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why the following code prints `0.00` and not `0`?

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("0.00");
big = big.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(big.toPlainString());
```

The following is the documentation for stripTrailingZeroes:

> Returns BigDecimal which is numerically equal to this one but with any trailing zeros removed from the representation. For example, stripping the trailing zeros from the BigDecimal value 600.0, which has [BigInteger, scale] components equals to [6000, 1], yields 6E2 with [BigInteger, scale] components equals to [6, -2]
> Returns:
> a numerically equal BigDecimal with any trailing zeros removed.

Comment: @eznme: Fixed, it too late here :))

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Surprisingly, the Java Compatibility Kit for Java 1.6 does not mention the `stripTrailingZeros` function at all. Well, except that the method must exist, but nothing more.

Comment: What is generally the procedure to report suspected issues with Java libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strips the trailing zeroes of the **internal** representation `[6000,1]` and adapts the scale accordingly `1 -> -2`. The internal representation is also somewhat independent of the final print-out which is also affected by format, rounding and locale.

Comment: How come `toPlainString` depends on `format` and `locale`? Rounding mode is used to `divide` so I don't think it influences `toPlainString` in any way. In fact, from the source code of `toPlainString` it doesn't look like that's the case either.

Comment: I dont mean toPlainString. I mean formatted output; in production you can rarely use toPlainString, you normally have to obide a specific format like 1234.567, 123E45 or 0.123*10**7; and you may not switch between them.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6480539