# Why does new BigDecimal("0.0").stripTrailingZeros() have a scale of 1?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Running this simple program:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    System.out.println(BigDecimal.ZERO.scale());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0").scale());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.0").stripTrailingZeros().scale());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.0").stripTrailingZeros().scale());
}
```

outputs:

```
0
0
1
0
```

My question is rather simple: why doesn't the third `println` output `0`? That would seem logical...

**EDIT**: OK, so, this is a very old bug:

[Bug Link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6480539)

and in fact, it "works" for any number of zeroes: `new BigDecimal("0.0000").stripTrailingZeroes().scale()` is 4!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clarification on behavior of BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeroes()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239137/clarification-on-behavior-of-bigdecimal-striptrailingzeroes)

Comment: The question Andrew is linking to is indeed the same, but be aware that the accepted answer is incorrect. The behaviour you see is the bug mentioned in the other answer: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6480539

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact "0.0" is the exception as it does no stripTrailingZeroes.
**A bug!**

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    p("0");
    p("0.0");
    p("1.0");
    p("1.00");
    p("1");
    p("11.0");
}

private static void p(String s) {
    BigDecimal stripped = new BigDecimal(s).stripTrailingZeros();
    System.out.println(s + " - scale: " + new BigDecimal(s).scale()
        + "; stripped: " + stripped.toPlainString() + " " + stripped.scale());
}

0 - scale: 0; stripped: 0 0
0.0 - scale: 1; stripped: 0.0 1
1.0 - scale: 1; stripped: 1 0
1.00 - scale: 2; stripped: 1 0
1 - scale: 0; stripped: 1 0
11.0 - scale: 1; stripped: 11 0
```

---

***Fixed in Java 8!*** See @vadim_shb's comment.

Comment: @AaronDigulla lol, bug since 2006. And will be fixed only in `Java 8`.

Comment: @Andremoniy: Don't count on it ;-)

Comment: The ongoing discussion at http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-February/014256.html suggests that the "fix" will be to document the behavior, not to change it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that is sad :/ Frankly, a method not behaving as it should should simply be fixed.

Comment: And it's fixed in JDK 8. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/2ee772cda1d6