# Convert BigDecimal to String with no trailing zeros

Tags: java, string-formatting, bigdecimal

I want to remove all trailing zeros from a BigDecimal and print it. But the trailingZeros method is not working as (I) expected.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("-11111111111111111111111111111111111111.111111111111111111111111111111");            
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("11111111111111111111111111111111111111.111111111111111111111111111111");
BigDecimal c = a.add(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c.toPlainString());
c = c.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c.toPlainString());
```

The output of this code is:

```
0E-30
0.000000000000000000000000000000
0E-30
0.000000000000000000000000000000
```

I would like a result of "0".

Comment: My results running the exact same code are slightly different:`0E-30
0.000000000000000000000000000000
0
0`

Comment: Hmm... that code prints "0" on the last two lines for me. Are you sure that's your *exact* code? Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Yes, the code is correct. My version:
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've found that it's a bug that was fixed in Java 8; please see [Why does new BigDecimal(“0.0”).stripTrailingZeros() have a scale of 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772323/why-does-new-bigdecimal0-0-striptrailingzeros-have-a-scale-of-1).

Comment: I Suppose it's [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6480539)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider That is the bug mentioned in the SO question I linked.

Comment: I guess it's time for an update then.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to create a formatted `String` according to your requirements.

**Example**

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2324.0011);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

String formatted = format.format(bd); // String now contains "2,324.00"
```

or

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2324.0011);
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");

String formatted = format.format(bd); // String now contains "2,324"
```

or with the values that you provided:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("-11111111111111111111111111111111111111.111111111111111111111111111111");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("11111111111111111111111111111111111111.111111111111111111111111111111");
BigDecimal c = a.add(b);

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");

System.out.println(format.format(c)); // prints "0"
```

You could strip any remaining trailing zeros with this regex `(?<=\d)\.?0+(?![\d\.])`, for example:

```
String value = "10000.343999000";
String stripped = value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\.?0+(?![\\d\\.])", ""); // now is 10000.343999
```

Comment: I don't know the number of non-zero digits after the decimal point in advance. I would like to print all of those digits.

Comment: in that case you could use a regex on resulted value

Comment: Actually it was answered that it is bug. I'll just update java. Thanks.