# Java BigDecimal formatting

Tags: java, jstl, bigdecimal

I have a class with BigDecimal field. I put this object to JSP (Spring MVC). And I need to display BigDecimal field without zero in decimal (20.00 like 20), that's why my getter method looks like

```
public BigDecimal getValue() {
    return value.stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

And I have the next result:

```
20.50 = 20.5;
13.25 = 13.25;
30.00 = 3E+1.
```

How can I change 3E+1 to 30 ? Can I format it with Java or JSTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple solution. It doesn't need to do stripTrailingZeros() in the getter method. Just

```
public BigDecimal getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

And on the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${object.value}" minFractionDigits="0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get away with just using toPlainString() on the returned bigdecimal.

Simple testing program:

```
    BigDecimal[] bds={new BigDecimal("1.0"),new BigDecimal("20.50"), 
              new BigDecimal("13.25"), 
              new BigDecimal("30.0"),
              new BigDecimal("30.01000"), new BigDecimal("0.0000")
    };
    for (BigDecimal bd: bds)
        System.out.println(bd+"==>"+bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

returns:

```
  1.0==>1
  20.50==>20.5
  13.25==>13.25
  30.0==>30
  30.01000==>30.01
  0.0000==>0.0000
```

There is only one boundary case that i know that it doesn't work for..and that is all variants of 0.

```
  0.0 => 0.0
  0.00 => 0.00
```

I believe this is covered in this stack overflow article: [Why does new BigDecimal("0.0").stripTrailingZeros() have a scale of 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772323/why-does-new-bigdecimal0-0-striptrailingzeros-have-a-scale-of-1)
As per the article, this is corrected in java 8 (but i haven't tested it yet).

You can get away with it by doing a compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)==0 and using BigDecimal.ZERO in that case.

```
BigDecimal[] bds={new BigDecimal("1.0"),
                  new BigDecimal("20.50"),
                  new BigDecimal("13.25"),
                  new BigDecimal("30.0"),
                  new BigDecimal("30.01000"), 
                  new BigDecimal("0.0000")
    };
    for (BigDecimal bd: bds){
        if (bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0){
            System.out.println(bd+"=>"+BigDecimal.ZERO);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(bd+"==>"+bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
        }
```

returns:

```
  1.0==>1
  20.50==>20.5
  13.25==>13.25
  30.0==>30
  30.01000==>30.01
  0.0000=>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the formatting method from `BigDecimal` to `String` (the framework is displaying the string returned from BigDecimal.toString()), you can use NumberFormat for better control of the displayed string.

According to the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format), you can implement a custom formatter for that job.

I suggest you to override the default `NumberFormatter` and override the `print` method, like so:

```
public class NoZeroesBigDecimalFormatter extends org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatter{
    @Override
    public String print(Number number, Locale locale) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(5); //whatever value is your maximum displayed digits
        return nf.format(value);
    }
}
```

Then, see how you can bind that formatter to your field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to override serialization. I want to know if there are some ways to format it on the server or UI.

Comment: @AlexSmith It's not overriding serialization, it's overriding the converting strategy on the framework.