# represent BigDecimal without decimal part as integer

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have to show `BigDecimal` value as integer if it doesnt'n have decimal part.

My solution generally works but the problem is when `bigDecResult` receives 
value with severals zeros after the point, like `0.0000`.

```
        BigDecimal bigDecResult = new BigDecimal("0.0000");

        if (bigDecResult.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).equals(0)) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(bigDecResult.intValue()));

        } else {
            System.out.println(bigDecResult.toString());
        }
```

How can I receive `0` in case of `bigDecResult = new BigDecimal("0.0000")`?

Comment: What version of Java? There is `.stripTrailingZeros()`, unfortunately [it is buggy for all JDK 7 versions and less](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14772323/1093528) (fortunately, it is fixed in Java 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.0000");

    if (bd.doubleValue() % 1 == 0.0 ){
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(0));

// You can also convert to Integer: 
// Integer response = bd.setScale(0).toBigInteger().intValue();

    } else {
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(4));
    }
```

Comment: But I need universal solution. I don't know beforehand will the value be 0.000, 0.000000001 or 123123123.000002

Comment: and integer value must be only in first case

Comment: Thank you buddy. Nice solution. In my case I just added } else {
    System.out.println(bd.toString()); 
    }