# Kotlin how to format Double number to String without zero after comma

Tags: android, kotlin

Suppose I have Double number which I want to convert to String.
I want to have an option which based on that I would have String number without trailing zeroes.

So for example:

- option with trailing zeros 123.00 -> "123,00", 123.324 -> "123,32"
- option without trailing zeroes 123.00 -> "123", 123.324 -> "123,32"

Is there a nice way to do this in Kotlin?

This is code which I have which I feel is rather ugly:

```
private const val VALUE_DIVIDER = 100
private const val DIGITS_AMOUNT = 2
private val defaultLocale = Locale("us")
private val currency = "$"
private val cents = 10000

    fun print(withoutTrailingZeros: Boolean = true): String {
        val price = (cents.toDouble() / VALUE_DIVIDER)
            .valueToString()
            .let { if (withoutTrailingZeros) it.removeSuffix(",00") else it }
        return "$price $currency"
    }

    private fun Double.valueToString() = round(DIGITS_AMOUNT).replace(".", ",")

    private fun Double.round(digits: Int): String =
        NumberFormat.getInstance(defaultLocale).apply {
            maximumFractionDigits = digits
            minimumFractionDigits = digits
            isGroupingUsed = false
        }.format(this)
```

**UPDATE**: The solution provided by @Roma Pochanin works partially, but strangely only as jUnit tests.
After I am running integration tests on Android emulator using this logic this is not working for 0 (it is formatted as "0,00" even when the withoutTrailingZeros flag is true). I heard about some bug related to that [Why does new BigDecimal("0.0").stripTrailingZeros() have a scale of 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772323/why-does-new-bigdecimal0-0-striptrailingzeros-have-a-scale-of-1/14772904#14772904)
but how it is connected with my case? Can anyone explain?

Please, see the exact sessions from debugger:

- working, as jUnit tests: https://ibb.co/HN9n41T
- bug, when running instrumentation tests on Android emulator: https://ibb.co/VCrmrMh

Comment: what do you need for 123.1? 123,1 or 123,10?

Comment: In that case 123,10

Comment: Did one of the answers help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for that in the Kotlin standard library, but you can specify the number of decimal places and the decimal format symbol using Java's `DecimalFormat`:

```
val formatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().apply {
    decimalSeparator = ','
}

val twoDecimalDigitsFormat = DecimalFormat("#.##").apply {
    decimalFormatSymbols = formatSymbols
}

val twoTrailingZerosFormat = DecimalFormat("#.00").apply {
    decimalFormatSymbols = formatSymbols
}

fun formatPrice(price: Double, withDecimalZeros: Boolean) = if (withDecimalZeros) {
    twoTrailingZerosFormat
} else {
    // Is number still the same after discarding places?
    if (price.toInt().toDouble() == price) {
        twoDecimalDigitsFormat
    } else {
        twoTrailingZerosFormat
    }
}.format(price)


println(formatPrice(123.00, true)) // 123,00
println(formatPrice(123.324, true)) // 132,32

println(formatPrice(123.00, false)) // 123
println(formatPrice(123.324, false)) // 123,32
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `BigDecimal`? It's like the default way to deal with prices and similar stuff. You also can consider using `BigDecimal`'s method `stripTrailingZeros`:

```
private const val VALUE_DIVIDER = 100
private const val DIGITS_AMOUNT = 2

private val currency = "$"
private val cents = 1298379

fun formatPrice(withoutDecimalZeros: Boolean = true) =
        BigDecimal(cents)
                .divide(BigDecimal(VALUE_DIVIDER), DIGITS_AMOUNT, RoundingMode.UP)
                .let { if (withoutDecimalZeros) it.stripTrailingZeros() else it }
                .toString().replace(".", ",")
                .let { "$it $currency" }
```

Comment: Why do people keep trying to use floating-point for things like currency where it's wholly inappropriate???  (Hint: it's a floating _binary_ point.  It simply can't store decimals exactly.  That's partly masked by rounding when converting to a decimal string for display, but it always shows through somewhere.)

Comment: It is not striping zeros for 0 -> 0 gets converted to 0,00 always (stripTrailingZeros not working in this case)

Comment: @K.Os, I don't think that price is supposed to be equal to zero. Moreover, the bug you described should have been fixed in Java 8. Which JDK you're using?